# How to del row data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My dataframe

[image]

I want to delete same row data when `col["SALE PRICE"] = '-'`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sales = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Downloads\\nyc-rolling-sales.csv',sep = ',',encoding = 'latin-1')

del sales['BOROUGH']
del sales['NEIGHBORHOOD']
del sales['BLOCK']
del sales['ADDRESS']
del sales['APARTMENT NUMBER']

sales['SALE PRICE'] = np.where(sales['SALE PRICE']=' -  ',delimeter, sales['SALE PRICE'])
```

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Answer (score 1):

You are checking equality with `=` rather than `==` on the following line

```
sales['SALE PRICE'] = np.where(sales['SALE PRICE']=' -  ',delimeter, sales['SALE PRICE'])
```

please change it to this

```
sales['SALE PRICE'] = np.where(sales['SALE PRICE']==' -  ',delimeter, sales['SALE PRICE'])
```

Answer (score 0):

**update**: Full code

How about this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = 'C:\\Users\\Jerry\\Downloads\\nyc-rolling-sales.csv'
sales = pd.read_csv(file,sep = ',',encoding = 'latin-1')

dropcols = ["BOROUGH","NEIGHBORHOOD","BLOCK","ADDRESS","APARTMENT NUMBER"]
sales = sales.drop(dropcols,axis=1)

#boolean indexing
mask = sales['SALE PRICE'] == "-"
#mask = sales['SALE PRICE'].str.strip() == "-" #use this for spaces
sales[~mask]
```

I don't know where you got that data, but you could also insert a direct link to it:

e.g.

```
url = "http://www1.nyc.gov/assets/finance/downloads/pdf/rolling_sales/rollingsales_manhattan.xls"
sales = pd.read_excel(url,skiprows=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df['sales price'] != '-']
```

See - https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dropping_column_and_rows.html